# Remove kay from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP and having a difficulty as follows -

I have a json like below -

```
[
  {
    "Severity_2": {
      "name": "Severity 2",
      "total_reported": 3,
      "client_reported": 2,
      "open": 3,
      "close": 0,
      "SAST": 0
    },
    "Severity_1": {
      "name": "Severity 1",
      "total_reported": 5,
      "client_reported": 0,
      "open": 5,
      "close": 0,
      "SAST": 0
    }
  }
]
```

I want to remove key names like Severity_1 and Severity_2 and want it as below -

```
[
    {
      "name": "Severity 2",
      "total_reported": 3,
      "client_reported": 2,
      "open": 3,
      "close": 0,
      "SAST": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Severity 1",
      "total_reported": 5,
      "client_reported": 0,
      "open": 5,
      "close": 0,
      "SAST": 0
    }
  
]
```

How can I do that? Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Will the data always contain "Severity_1" etc, or does the solution need to be generic? And like @WaisKamal asked, typically you should show us why your attempt isn't working, rather than solving it 'our way'.

Comment: hint: json_decode, array_values and json_encode

Answer (score 0):

Decode the JSON, capture the array_values (that gets rid of the keys), then encode it back to JSON. To see it in the format you mentioned, you can use the flag `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
<?php
$json = <<<EOT
  {
    "Severity_2": {
      "name": "Severity 2",
      "total_reported": 3,
      "client_reported": 2,
      "open": 3,
      "close": 0,
      "SAST": 0
    },
    "Severity_1": {
      "name": "Severity 1",
      "total_reported": 5,
      "client_reported": 0,
      "open": 5,
      "close": 0,
      "SAST": 0
    }
  }
EOT;

$array=json_decode($json, true);
$new = array_values($array);
$new = json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($new);
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/3euq0ptlVSUhdMMV